# Continuously swap two inline span elements in and out using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have webpage that contains a unordered list of text (languages).  On each line is the the English translation and the native translation of that language wrapped in SPAN tags:

```
<li><span class="eng">German</span><span class="non">Deutsche</span></li>
<li><span class="eng">Denmark</span><span class="non">Dansk</span></li>
```

All I want to do is have the page toggle back and forth between the English span and the Native span ever 5 seconds or so.  The code below works fine except that it slowly speeds up over time.  Any idea how I can tweak it to keep it constant?

```
function myRepeat() {

    var aniTime = 500;

    $('.eng').fadeToggle(aniTime).delay(aniTime);
    $('.non').fadeToggle(aniTime).delay(aniTime);

}

setInterval(myRepeat, 8000);
```

Comment: Can you provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: is it the same in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using CSS over JS. This has the benefit of being hardware accelerated and easier to maintain.

You can use a keyframe animation which fades the elements in/out. The same animation can be applied to both `span` elements, but just delay the `.non` elements by half the total animation run time, something like this:

```css
@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  5% {  opacity: 1; }
  45% { opacity: 1; }
  50% {  opacity: 0; }
}

li span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOut 10s infinite;
}

li span.non {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="eng">German</span>
    <span class="non">Deutsche</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="eng">Denmark</span>
    <span class="non">Dansk</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```